# How to create procedure with to Keep Track of Last Changed Data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So i have two tables: User and LogUser. When i update table User the old data should be keep for history in LogUser table.

I have created procedure for update, but don't know how to keep history of changed data.

Update Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateUser
(
@UserID int,
@Name nvarchar(40),
@Address nvarchar(60),
@City nvarchar(15),
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
UPDATE [dbo].[User] SET [UserID] = @UserID, [Name] = @Name, [Address] = @Address, [City] =  @City,WHERE (([UserID] = @UserID));
```

PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateUser
(
@UserID int,
@Name nvarchar(40),
@Address nvarchar(60),
@City nvarchar(15)
)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO
    dbo.LogUser (UserID, Name, Address, City)
SELECT
    UserID, Name, Address, City
FROM
    dbo.User
WHERE
    UserID = @UserID;

UPDATE
        dbo.User
    SET
        UserID = @UserID,
        Name = @Name,
        Address = @Address,
        City = @City
    WHERE
        UserID = @UserID;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about inserting the data into the LogUser table before you update it?

```
-- Step 1: Add user history into LogUser table
INSERT INTO
    dbo.LogUser (UserID, Name, Address, City)
SELECT
    UserID, Name, Address, City
FROM
    dbo.User
WHERE
    UserID = @UserID;

-- Step 2: Update the user in the User table
UPDATE
    dbo.User
SET
    Name = @Name,
    Address = @Address,
    City = @City
WHERE
    UserID = @UserID;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i needed. So does my procedure should look like this now? .. edited question.

Comment: Yep. I made one change to the code above: I removed the "SET UserID = @UserID", as this was superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create dbo.LogUser

   create table dbo.LogUser (
       action varchar(3),
       changedAt datetime,
       userID nchar(5),      -- why not int ???
       Name nvarchar(40),
       Address nvarchar(60),
       City nvarchar(15) )
2. Use trigger on dbo.User

   create trigger dbo.User_UPD on dbo.User
   for update, delete
   as begin
   insert dbo.LogUser
   select case when i.UserID is null then 'Del' else 'Upd' end,
          GETDATE(),
           d.UserID,
           d.Name,
           d.Address,
           d.City
   from deleted d
   left join inserted i on i.UserID = d.UserID
   end
3. Update dbo.Users as You want.

   Update dbo.Users
   Set Name = 'Joe'

Comment: Thank you for the answer, userId is int, i got it wrong in the question.